# Ggplot, how to have two lines in same chart and have it produce a legend

Tags: r, ggplot2, dplyr

Below is the sample code. It produces a two line chart. However, the legend does not populate. I know how to add code for a legend. However, in this case the code works (produces no errors) but no legend comes about. Any ideas as to what I am missing? The desired result would show AvgFSize and its corresponding color as well as AvgHSize and its corresponding color in the bottom.

```
 avgFSize1<-c(2,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11)
 avgHSize1<-c(4,5,7,9,10,12,13,15,17)
 year1<-c(2010,2011,2012,2013,2014,2015,2016,2017,2018)
 singleh<-c(101,102,103,105,106,107,111,113,118)

 library(dplyr)
 library(ggplot2)


 testitem <- data.frame(avgFSize1, avgHSize1, year1, singleh)


chart26<-testitem%>%ggplot(aes(x=year1))+
geom_line(aes(y=avgHSize1), color = "black")+
geom_line(aes(y=avgFSize1), color = "red")+theme(legend.position="bottom", legend.box = 
"horizontal")+ggtitle("Average Household and Family Size")+
labs(y="AVerage Household and Family Size")

chart26
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Essentially you did all the correct things, but forgot to move `color` inside the `mapping = aes()`.

```
testitem %>% ggplot(aes(x=year1))+
        geom_line(aes(y=avgHSize1, color = "black"))+
        geom_line(aes(y=avgFSize1, color = "red"))  +
        theme(legend.position="bottom", legend.box = "horizontal")+
        ggtitle("Average Household and Family Size")+
        labs(y="AVerage Household and Family Size") +
        scale_color_manual(
                labels = c("Household Size", "Family Size"),
                values = c("black", "red")
        )
```

[image: GGPLOT with Custom Labels.]

Comment: how would I have the legend says "AvgFSize" and "AvgHSize"?